# How do I make my rendered buttons search for what they are labeled as with Giphy API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button

I want the buttons to search for what they are labeled as. I am assuming that whatever will make it work the way it should, would go where it says 'Misfits'.

I tried putting in the id for the div where the buttons are rendered into where it says 'Misfits'.

```
function renderButtons() {
$("#band-buttons").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    var a = $("<button data-bands='Misfits'>");
    a.addClass("band");
    a.attr("data-name", topics[i]);
    a.text(topics[i]);
    $("#band-buttons").append(a);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(i);
}
```

}

It should search for what button is labeled. Right now every button searches for Misfits. I know that is b/c Misfits assigned to data-bands. It's just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderButtons() {
$("#band-buttons").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    var a = $("<button data-bands='" + topics[i] + "'>");
    a.addClass("band");
    a.attr("data-name", topics[i]);
    a.text(topics[i]);
    $("#band-buttons").append(a);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(i);
}
```

}